# Problema com acentos no .serialize()

Tags: jquery, html, codificação-de-caracteres, serialização

O **.serialize();** pega todas as informações do form, porém com as acentuação diferente

ex: **PÃO** fica **P%C3%83O** , quando testo o app no localhost os acentos funcionam certinho mas quando hospedo fica assim **PÃ£O**  ???

Fiz este [exmplo](http://jsfiddle.net/fabiosm/205m04vd/)

```
 <form name='meuForm' method='post' action='action' id='formStr'>
   <input type='text'   name='str1' value='palhação' id='str1'  />
   <input type='text'   name='str2' value='Fábio'    id='str2' />  
   <input type='submit' id='teste'  valiue='testar' />  </form>
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( e ) {  e.preventDefault(); var str1 = $('#str1').val();    var formSerializado = $(this).serialize();  console.log( 'str1 = '+str1+', formSerializado = '+ formSerializado ); });
```

No console.log() fica

```
str1 = palhação, formSerializado = str1=palha%C3%A7%C3%A3o&str2=F%C3%A1bio
```

e gostaria de entender porque quando tenho o valor da var str1 o valor fica certo e quando serializo fica estranho, acredito ser o mesmo motivo que a minha app está dando problema de acentuação.

Para evitar problema no site uso `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >` 
em todas as páginas.

Existe forma de codificar ao serializar?

Comment: palha%C3%A7%C3%A3o&str2=F%C3%A1bio está correto em UTF-8. O problema parece ser na hora de mostrar os dados. Lembre-se de setar o charset no meta também: `<meta charset="utf-8">` para ter certeza do que está acontecendo.

Comment: @Bacco - Isso mesmo. É necessário apenas tratar essa _string_. em PHP pode ser feito com `utf8_decode()`.

Comment: estou usando JavaServlets e na servlet a letra **Á** fica **Ã¡**

Comment: verifique se você não está decodificando a string duas vezes no mesmo código por engano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o manual de [jQuery.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) é criada uma string UTF-8 no padrão URL-Encoding, também conhecido como [Percentage Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) de todos os ["controles de sucesso"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) do formulário.

Não é que seu *output* esteja errado, ele apenas está diferente daquilo que você esperava. Resta tratar com a linguagem *server-side*.

Quanto ao estar usando JavaServlets, talvez [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469874/how-do-i-correctly-decode-unicode-parameters-passed-to-a-servlet) do Stack Overflow inglês lhe ajude.

Comment: Obrigado. tenho isso na servlet **response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");       request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");** e funciona no localhost mas na hospedagem não!? o quer será

Comment: Isso são outros quinhentos e, para isso, talvez justificaria criar um novo tópico. No entanto, **talvez** o mesmo seria fechado por descontextualização.

Comment: tem razão. obrigado

Comment: Se a resposta ajudou, não esqueça de pelo menos marcá-la como tanto.